# how to calculate within a procedure by the result of two queries

Tags: mysql

I have a Table called TblOrders.the fields are `FldSlNo`, `FldStrategyID`, `FldTradeServerName`, `FldBaseDir`, `FldBinaryStartTime`, `FldInstrumentID`, `FldOrderNumber`, `FldBuySell`, `FldDisplayQuantity`, `FldRemainingQuantity`, `FldTotalTradeQuantity`, `FldLastTradePrice`,      `FldLastTradeQuantity`, `FldPrice`, `FldOrderTime`, `FldReferenceText` and  `FldOrderStatusID`. Now I have a procedure called `ProfitCalculation`.

the procedure is given below:

```
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE ProfitCalculation
     (
        IN   instrument                      INT(20)       , 
        OUT  profit                          float(10,2)
     )
BEGIN 

DECLARE buy DECIMAL(10,2);
DECLARE sell DECIMAL(10,2);
DECLARE oprofit DECIMAL(8,2);

    SELECT SUM(FldLastTradeQuantity*FldPrice)                             
    FROM   TblOrders
    WHERE  FldInstrumentID = instrument AND FldBuySell = 'b' AND FldLastTradePrice != 0 AND FldLastTradeQuantity != 0 group by FldInstrumentID INTO buy;

    SELECT SUM(FldLastTradeQuantity*FldPrice)                    
    FROM   TblOrders
    WHERE  FldInstrumentID = instrument AND FldBuySell = 's' AND FldLastTradePrice != 0 AND FldLastTradeQuantity != 0 group by FldInstrumentID INTO sell; 

    SELECT (sell-buy) INTO oprofit;
    SELECT oprofit INTO profit; 
END 
//
delimiter ;
```

It always return null.
Is there have any solution for this problem.
Please help me out..
Thanks in advance

Comment: As a side comment, you don't need the table ('tbl') and field ('fld') prefixes, it hinders readability.

Answer (score 0):

First, on both of the queries, you're specifying a `GROUP BY`, but expecting a single result. Since you're already including the grouped field in the where clause, this is not necessary.

Secondly, try running the individual statements (without the 'INTO' statement) - my guess is that at least one of them is returning NULL, causing the output to be null. If you would prefer zero to NULL as an output with an empty recordset, wrap the `SUM()` statement in `COALESCE`, as in:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(FldLastTradeQuantity*FldPrice), 0)
```

This way, if one of the two statements return NULL, the other one will still work.

Specifying the conditions `FldLastTradePrice != 0 AND FldLastTradeQuantity != 0` are unnecessary, as they'd be handled within the SUM statement.

Comment: FldLastTradePrice != 0 AND FldLastTradeQuantity != 0 this is necessary because depending upon this condition I have to fetch the result..